# Adding Embedded Images to Dynamic Gallery via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Does anyone know how to pass images from path or from images embedded in images/ directory ( in static gallery mode they show up without any problems) to getItemImage customUI dynamic gallery handler?

I was trying to refer to an image with path like so:

```
Sub Gallery1_getItemImage(control As IRibbonControl, index As Integer, ByRef returnedVal)
    Select Case control.id
    Case "Gallery1": returnedVal = "C:\Boxes\Comapny_Box1.png"
    End Select
End Sub
```

and I can't see any results in my procedurally generated Gallery objects. I thought that with images embedded within excel file I could refer with the same way as with mso icons (just like with code below - which works for mso icons). Do I have to use some special method to refer to it?

```
Sub Gallery1_getItemImage(control As IRibbonControl, index As Integer, ByRef returnedVal)
    Select Case control.id
    Case "Gallery1": returnedVal = "ChartStylesGallery"
    End Select
End Sub
```

I also tried to use `returnedVal = LoadPicture("C:\Boxes\Company_Box1.png")` but I get invalid picture error.

Best Regards

Comment: how about `ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert ("C:\Images\pic.jpg")`?

Comment: no, this way I would add a picture to the Worksheet. What I am trying to do is to add Picture as item's icon in custom ribbon gallery.

Comment: right I missed that I am sorry for the confusion I created.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out how to feed this handler with external graphic files.
The code that worked looks like that:

```
Sub Gallery1_getItemImage(control As IRibbonControl, index As Integer, _
ByRef returnedVal)

    Select Case control.id
       Case "Gallery1": Set returnedVal = LoadPicture("C:\Boxes\Company_Box1.bmp")
    End Select

End Sub
```

I had to use bmp files instead of png, and use Set statement and LoadPicture() method.

Comment: Still I don't have any idea how could I refer to a graphic file that is "zipped" into excel file.

Comment: did you figure it out? I have the same problem!